# Ideas Surrounding the SIRS model

Tags: mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes

We are working on the SIRS model in my physical analysis course, and I
want to prove that all solutions in the triangular region
$\Delta$ tend to the equilibrium point $(\tau,0)$ when the total
population doesn't exceed threshold level for the disease. I know
that when $\tau = \frac{v}{\beta},$ the two equilibria coalesce at
$(\tau,0).$ That being said, I am having some issues connecting
this idea to the behavior of $\Delta$ in the model. I think that
I may need some assistance on this problem. For reference, $\Delta$
is the region where $I,S \geq 0 \wedge S+I \leq \tau.$

Comment: I think you have to write the exact model and define all parameters. Also, what do you mean by "behaviour" of a region? Maybe you want to analyse bifurcations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that the $\Delta$ region is a [positively invariant set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_invariant_set). You can verify that analyzing the slope field at the boundary of $\Delta$. Expect to find no vector pointing outwards $\Delta$. So once a solution curve gets in $\Delta$ it never gets out.

You can better understand the behavior of the system near $(\tau, 0)$ by studying the linearized system around it. Therefore I suggest to linearize the system around $(\tau, 0)$ and rewrite it as a matrix differential equation.

Let **A** be the matrix of coefficients.

Consider the case when $\tau \lt \frac{v}{\beta}$.

Verify that **A** has two negative real eigenvalues. This means that the equilibrium point $(\tau, 0)$ for some neighborhood of itself behaves like a spiral sink (on a twisted fashion) and so it is asymptotically stable.

Now suppose that $\tau = \frac{v}{\beta}$.

Hence **A** no longer have a pair of negative real eigenvalues. Take a look at the direction field around the point $(\tau, 0)$. It no longer resembles any linear pattern we know. We would need a more refined technique solely to analyze this singularity.

Thus I will leave you with this question to reason:

What are the chances of finding an instance on the nature of the modeled phenomenon such that $\tau = \frac{v}{\beta}$ for all time?

(Bibliography: Hirsch, Smale, and Devaney, Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos (Edition: 2), Elsevier Science & Technology Books, 2004)